# Cross platform (android+ios) solution in unity3d to save user name and password

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

We are using unity3d.
We wish to save the username and password to something secure (and also that will survive app deletion) in ios and in android.
We know that in ios there is the keychain that we can use.
Do you know of any good cross platform plugin or some custom code we can use?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is using some remote server.
Just store the information to the device ID.

Or you can try somthing like

```
  #if UNITY_ANDROID
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    //Create your file on sdCard
  #endif

  #if UNITY_IPHONE
    //Save on keychain
  #endif
```